# Drupal - Get image from url and import it into node

Tags: drupal, drupal-files

Im writing a module for drupal, Im trying to create a node from my module, everything is fine , I only have 1 problem with creating an image , The image exist on different server, so I want to grab the page and insert it , I install module http://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources , which has remote option , I search in the module code , I could not find the function that he used for this process, module work very nice from interface , but how i make it do the job from code ? which function should i call and what parameter should i pass .

I'm over Drupal 6.

Answer (score 10):

Hopefully you're using Drupal 7...

The [`system_retrieve_file()` function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.module/function/system_retrieve_file/7) will download a file from a remote source, copy it from temp to a specified destination and optionally save it to the `file_managed` table if you want it to be managed.

```
$managed = TRUE; // Whether or not to create a Drupal file record
$path = system_retrieve_file($url, 'public://my_files/', $managed);
```

If you want to get the file object immediately after you've done this, the following is the only way I've found so far:

```
$file = file_load(db_query('SELECT MAX(fid) FROM {file_managed}')->fetchField());
```

Comment: I had to change `SELECT MAX(id)` to `SELECT MAX(fid)` into the last query since the id column didn't exist in Drupal 7.17:

Answer (score 4):

get fid using $path->fid. no need to mysql